# Error while running coverage run in python

Tags: python, code-coverage, python-unittest

i want to run coverage test for my `test_morse_assertpy.py`.

```
import unittest
from src.sample.Morse import Morse
from assertpy import assert_that


# użycie unittesta i assertpy wymiennie
class TestMorse(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.temp = Morse()

    def test_morse_single_letter(self):
        morse = ".- "
        inputed_data = "A"
        self.assertEqual(morse, self.temp.coding(inputed_data))

    def test_morse_word(self):
        morse = ".-- --- -.. .- "
        inputed_data = "woda"
        self.assertEqual(morse, self.temp.coding(inputed_data))

    def test_morse_word_2(self):
        morse = ".... --- .--. "
        inputed_data = "hop"
        self.assertEqual(morse, self.temp.coding(inputed_data))

    def test_morse_numbers(self):
        inputed_data = "1234567890"
        morse = ".---- ..--- ...-- ....- ..... -.... --... ---.. ----. ----- "
        self.assertEqual(morse, self.temp.coding(inputed_data))
```

and some more tests...
But when i run `coverage run tests/test_morse_assertpy.py`   
I get an error:

```
    from src.sample.Morse import Morse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

The Morse.py file is in the src/sample/Morse.py, and i dont undersant why it says that there is no module named `src`

Comment: how have you installed the src module or configured it to be in your python PATH?

Comment: What do you mean how i installed the modul? I just created a directory called that and inside i put this Morse.py file.

Comment: Well python only looks for modules in the paths that are insideits configured paths. So if you have just created this dir and not told python that it should consder this dir as a place it can find modules then it wont know about `src`. maybe have a quick read here on how python searches for modules https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: Well, so what i should exactly? ;/

Comment: did you read the details in the link? the easiest way would be to create or ammend the environment variable PYTHON_PATH and add the path to your dir where the module is, that way python will look in that dir when searching for the `src` module